# unable to nevigate to the action method in ASP.Net MVC with javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

On dropdown change event in ASP.Net MVC 6 I am calling a Javascript function to call the action method but some how but I am getting the error as if the action does not exists.

[image]

URL

```
         window.location.href = "/QualStandard/Test?tableName=" + "table";
```

Comment: Please post the controller code